# CSS files is not loading at the browser

Tags: html, css

I know there are several people already asked this type of question but in my case the condition is different. I'm using `CSS` files from my `domain` to my `subdomain`.

My page:- https://forms.alapdorl.xyz/public/login

The problem is that when I'm opening my page in another browser or in **incognito mode**, the browser doesn't cache my CSS files

[image: When opening in another browser or incognito mode]

but when I open my CSS files manually and then refresh the page it applies.

[image: My page after opening css files manually]

Here's my Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
    <title>Login - Alapdorl</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/" crossorigin>
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#206bc4"/>
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#206bc4"/>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent"/>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True"/>
    <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320"/>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow,noarchive"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://alapdorl.xyz/assets/css/tabler.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://alapdorl.xyz/assets/css/demo.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <style> .separtor { display: flex; flex-direction: row; } .separtor:before, .separtor:after{ content: ""; flex: 1 1; border-bottom: 1px solid #dcdcdc; margin: auto; } .separtor:before { margin-right: 10px } .separtor:after { margin-left: 10px } </style>
  </head>
  <body class="antialiased">
     <div class="page" style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center">
               <div class="container">
          <div class="page-header" style="margin-top: -13%">
          <center>       
          <div class="col">
                <h1 class="page-title" style="font-size: 25px">Login</h1>
              </div>
            </center>
          </div>
       <div class="row justify-content-center">
       <div class="col">
              <form class="card card-lg" action="" method="post">
                <div class="card-body">
                <div class="mb-3">
  <label class="form-label">E-mail</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="you@yourmail.com" autocomplete="off" required/>
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
  <label class="form-label">Password</label>
  <div class="input-group input-group-flat">
  <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="•••••••" required/>
    <span class="input-group-text">
    <button class="material-icons" style="background:none;border:none;outline:none;font-size: 20px;color:inherit"> visibility </button>
    <button class="material-icons d-none" style="background:none;border:none;outline:none;font-size: 20px;color:inherit"> visibility_off </button>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-footer"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button></div>
<br>
                  <h5 class="separtor container">Or</h5>
<div class="form-footer"><a href="/login/index" class="btn btn-white btn-block"><img src="//alapdorl.xyz/assets/img/google_icon.png" height="20" style="float:left">&nbsp;Continue with Google</a></div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>    

       
    </body>
</html>
```

**Update:-**

> Can I move my files to my subdomain

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console? And have you tried clearing the cache in regular (not-incognito) mode? To check you're not just seeing an old cached copy, and it is in fact broken everywhere.

Comment: Checking in the network panel in Chrome, the size for both `tabler.css` and `demo.min.css` is shown as “0 bytes” at first. But it is then enough to load the first one, tabler.css, in a new tab - if I reload the page after that, then suddenly it shows a size different from 0 for _both_ of them. The console shows a couple of warnings about the corresponding source maps not being able to load, but only getting 404 for those requests - not sure if that is somehow related.

Comment: What is the return message of the http request?

Comment: @MarkBaijens before opening css files getting 400

Comment: @Amaanwarsi http status `400` indicate a `bad request`. Check your server logs for more information about what is wrong.

Comment: @DBS I will checked it by clearing cache,  problem is not changed yet 

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely a problem on your server. Your server return the wrong MIME type for css files (text/html instead of text/css).

You can check this with the browser console.

Answer (score 0):

I dont really know the problem but when i open your website the css didnt apply too. I think there's a problem with the browser that you usually use to test the css code. I assume The css code is not updated because of caching so you still see that your website using the css.

Try to use `?v=1.01` behind `style.css` so the code look like `style.css?v=1.01` to prevent caching.